# What is the best Chinese equivalent for "passion" or "to be passionate about something"?

Tags: expressions, translation

In English, it is common to say you are "passionate about something" or "something is your passion" (e.g. *My passion is rockclimbing*).

This use of 'passion' is different to 'passion' as in relationships/emotions etc.

What Chinese expression would be suitable to indicate 'passion' in the sense of "My passion is rockclimbing"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, passion could be translated into "热情"(zeal),"激情"(deep love), or "爱好"(hobby). Note that "激情" could also mean "passion" as in romantic relationships.

I would like to describe the pattern for this word. In general, you would say "对X的热情/激情/爱好" to mean "passion for X".

And for your example "My passion is rockclimbing", you could say "我的爱好是攀岩", or “我对攀岩富有热情/激情", but I would like to express it in a simple way,

> 我酷爱攀岩。

"酷爱" means "to love something deep" as a verb here.

Comment: Nice answer! 热爱 is more common than 酷爱, I think. 特别喜欢 also works.

Comment: in my opinion. 酷爱 is deeper than 热爱. that's  why i use it for passion.

Comment: How about 狂熱(enthusiastic), or 非常狂熱. Actually I use this more, maybe just because I like to express things exaggerated?

Comment: @ShouYa Definitely exaggerated.

Comment: @Shou Ya 狂热 sounds a little negative to me. you know, 狂 means "mad","insane“. of  course, you can use that word, as in English. you can use words like "wicked","awesome" when you want to say something is so great,

Comment: @Hang Not really, I think. Sometimes we could say something like 'I'm crazy on fishing.' It doesn't matter and it does not have any meaning negative I suppose. We could also say 「我很狂熱於釣魚。」 in Chinese. And it sounds proper also, isn't that?

Answer (score 1):

A common term that I often come across is 热衷于. It's normally used in conjunction with an intensifier like 十分 or 非常.

*My passion is rockclimbing:*

> 我非常热衷于攀岩.